# JHipster Okta gateway application is not authenticating

Tags: jhipster, spring-security-oauth2, okta

I generated a gateway application with JHipster to test oauth2 through Okta for my organization. I didn't make any changes to the code beyond what was recommended in the readme: The client ID and Secret are in the yml, as well as the issuer uri.

It redirects me to Okta. I log in. It redirects back as expected. Then I got an unauthorized error at /login?error. So I tried adding a permitAll for /login/**. This resulted in error 404.

Something in the recommended configuration is not working as expected.

**application.yml**:

```
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            issuer-uri: https://dev-[numbers].okta.com/oauth2/default
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: {my real client id}
            client-secret: {my client secret}
            scopes:
              - profile
              - email
              - openid
              - customScope
```

What am I doing wrong?
Could it be the environment variables are not being read?

From **.okta.env**, but I also added them to the environment variables in the intellij configuration

```
export SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_USER_AUTHORIZATION_URI="https://dev-[number].okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize"
export SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCE_USER_INFO_URI="https://dev-[number].okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo"
export SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCE_TOKEN_INFO_URI="https://dev-[number].okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/introspect"
export SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_CLIENT_ID={clientid}
export SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_CLIENT_SECRET={clientsecret}
```

Comment: Did you use the Okta CLI to configure JHipster? That's the recommended way to set things up so you get the proper groups added and `groups` claim configured in the ID token. Here's a video that shows how it works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThytrcxL31s

Comment: I tried after watching your videos/reading your articles (I'm a fan, btw). But Okta CLI won't work on my system. It errors, "unable to find valid certification path". Probably because we're behind some firewalls here. I spent a day trying to get around it with no luck. That leaves me with trying to configure this myself.

Comment: The JHipster docs show you how to configure things through the Okta Admin Console: https://www.jhipster.tech/security/#okta

Comment: Thanks, I followed those directions and I get an error returned from Okta, in the URL:
"error=invalid_scope&error_description=The+authorization+server+resource+does+not+have+any+configured+default+scopes%2C+%27scope%27+must+be+provided." The instructions don't mention anything about needing to add a custom scope. That does fix this particular issue, but the result is the same as above.

Comment: Do you have a "default" authorization server under Security > API? If you don't, you can create a new developer account at developer.okta.com/signup. If you're using a workforce account (instead of a developer account), you will have to pay for API Access Management for this feature.

Comment: I do. Actually, I figured it out. I'd changed the Java version to 8 because Intellij was giving me trouble on 11. Turns out I should've left it at 11. My bad! Sorry, Matt, your products are great. Let this be a cautionary tale for anyone else in the same boat--don't touch the version.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you figured it out!